# Minimum volume is to loud

Tags: volume-control, volume

I have bought a new Alcatel Pop 4S which I'm quite happy with, but one thing is really annoying. No matter if I'm using build in speaker or headphones, outgoing sounds are really loud for me. I have found that "minimum" loudness is 6% so I wonder if there is some shell command to set up loudness to e.g. 2%. I know that there is app called "Fine Volume Control V2", but I don't want to pay just for this one function if there is some another solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you checked to see if Alcatel installed an app already for "volume boost"? On my tablet, there is one called "SRS TrueMedia" that really kicks up the minimum volume.

Comment: If they did install an app, check to see if you can disable it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no app called "SRS TrueMedia" or anything similar, but I have found app called "ArkamysAudio". I will try to disable it for a while and test, if it helps.

Comment: So, it had no influence on loudness.

Comment: If you would have any other idea, I will be happy for your advice. Thanks :)

Comment: Check Settings->Volumes

Comment: Thanks, but that was one of the first things, which I have tried.

Comment: You can try these apps:     LINK 1    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TEST.android.lvh     LINK 2 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cb.volumePlus

Comment: Still the same behavior - when I go under the 3% then there is no sound anymore. But thank you a lot, I will probably buy some suitable "resistor" or I will get used to it. Anyway thanks for your advice. :)